# How to change distances between labels on Y axis in pyplot?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am doing a plot of "travelling time" with time on x axis and checkpoints on y axis (Checkpoints are only names, and one checkpoint corresponds with one timestamp).
The code for plotting itself is:

```
if checkpoints:
  plt.plot_date(timestamps,checkpoints,color = "b",linestyle='solid')
else:
  plt.plot_date(timestamps,distances,color = "b",linestyle='solid')
```

*Timestamps*: list of hours:mins,
*checkpoints*: list of strings,
*distances*: list of ints

I would need to remake the plot with different spacings on y axis, as the distance between checkpoints varies. This, I guess, can be achieved with using distance array as 2nd argument, but I have no clue how should I rename the distance labels so they correspond with the checkpoints.

Edit:

Data used:

Timestamps: They are converted by command `datetime.strptime(timestamp, "%H:%M")` and collected in an array.
Input data as following:

```
4:45 4:48 4:51 4:52 4:53 4:54 4:55 4:56 5:15 5:19 5:24 5:25 5:26 5:28 5:29 5:30 5:33 5:35 5:39 5:40 5:42 5:43 5:44 5:45 5:39 5:40 5:46 5:47 5:48 5:50 5:51 5:52
```

Checkpoints: An array of strings, with the same length as timestamps. They are periodically repeated to match the timestamps:

```
[ 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H','A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H','A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H' ]
```

Distances: Similar to checkpoints, but they are integers, not strings.

```
[ 0, 9, 12, 16, 18, 21, 23, 24, 0, 9, 12, 16, 18, 21, 23, 24, 0, 9, 12, 16, 18, 21, 23, 24, 0, 9, 12, 16, 18, 21, 23, 24 ]
```

Produced output with checkpoints and timestamps:

[image: Example 1]

What I don't like is the even distance between checkpoints.

I would like to achieve this - the output with distances and timestamps (Numbers on Y axis are distances from checkpoint A), but with labels from the first example:

[image: Example 2]

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow! Since you are new, please take a moment to read [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

You will get a better chance at getting an answer if you provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) including mock-up data. In particular, refer to [How to make good reproducible pandas examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples)

Comment: Please provide also your data (*timestamps* and *checkpoints*).
Assuming that both of them are separate *Series* objects,
where do you have locations of each set of points?
Maybe when you include your data it will be clear.

Comment: Your post includes *Distances* (looks like ordinary *pythonic* list). Where is it used in your code?

Comment: Pyplot accepts one list for x axis and one list for y axis. In my code, I have only replaced checkpoints with distances and casted them into integer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key to success is to use in *y* axis **distances** of checkpoints,
instead of their text labels.

Your data needed here are:

```
ts = [
    '4:45', '4:48', '4:51', '4:52', '4:53', '4:54', '4:55', '4:56',
    '5:15', '5:19', '5:24', '5:25', '5:26', '5:28', '5:29', '5:30',
    '5:33', '5:35', '5:39', '5:40', '5:42', '5:43', '5:44', '5:45',
    '5:39', '5:40', '5:46', '5:47', '5:48', '5:50', '5:51', '5:52']
chkDist = [0, 9, 12, 16, 18, 21, 23, 24]
chkLbl  = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H']
```

Checkpoint distances and labels are without repetitions.

Let's start from conversion of your data. Generate a DataFrame with:

- 4 columns for each line (cut *ts* into rows and then transform),
- the index as *dist*,
- and convert strings to *datetime*.

The code to do it is:

```
timestamps = pd.DataFrame(np.array(ts).reshape((4, -1)).T,
    index=chkDist).apply(pd.to_datetime)
```

The date part is taken from the current day, but actually it doesn't matter.

Convert also checkpoint distances and labels to a *Series*:

```
chkLabels = pd.Series(chkLbl, index=chkDist)
```

Then generate your picture as follows:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as mdates

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(6, 4), constrained_layout=True)
plt.plot_date(timestamps, timestamps.index, color='b', linestyle='solid')
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(mdates.MinuteLocator(byminute=range(0,60,15)))
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter(fmt='%H:%M'))
plt.xticks(rotation=30)
for dist, lbl in chkLabels.iteritems():
    plt.text(xLbl, dist, lbl, ha='center', va='center')
ax.set_yticks(chkDist, minor=True)
plt.grid(which='minor', linestyle='--')
plt.grid(which='major')
plt.show()
```

Note that *timestamps* is a *DataFrame*, so from each of its columns
there is generated separate line.
I used *MinuteLocator* to have *x* labels every 15 minutes and
*DateFormatter* to format them.

To print checkpoint labels I used additional loop, iterating over
*chkLabels* and printing each label.

Note however that text coordinates for *plt.text* are expressed in
**data coordinates**, so:

- *y* coordinates are taken from the index of *chkLabels*,
- but *x* coordinates are expressed as *minimal time - 10 min*.

And the last step is to print the grid. For *minor* lines I used
*set_yticks* with *y* taken from *chkDist*. Then I called *plt.grid*,
separately for *minor* lines, with explicit specification of the linestyle,
and for *major* lines, with default attributes.

For  your data I got the following result:

[image]

Note that checkpoint labels are sometimes very close to each other (in
this case *G* and *H*).
So if they were **overlapping** each other, you should modify the code
to print only selected labels, e.g. by dropping some elements from
*chkLabels*.

Comment: Well, that is where I got... but with checkpoints, the only displayed horizontal bars were the ones intersecting the dots.

So I would like to have checkpoint "names" in the left column, but they should be at the same level as the dots are. Not the numbers.

Comment: I modified my solution, so that now checkpoint labels are also printed.

Comment: The only thing I miss now is how to print the horizontal lines on the same level as the checkpoints/dots (instead of how they are currently - each 5 kilometres).

Comment: I added *minor* grid lines at the position of each checkpoint, but left *major* lines, just as it is on your picture of the expected result.

Comment: Only extra thing needed was to use `plt.yticks(distances,checkpoints)` . Thanks!